# How to calculate if the sum of integers from 1 to X are prime

Tags: java

A while back I was given a problem that looked something like this:

A lucky number is a number where the sum of the numbers before it (including itself) is prime. For example, two is a lucky number because it becomes 1 + 2. Since this is 3, and 3 is a prime number, we can conclude that 2 is a lucky number.

I've tried constructing a simple code to find a few lucky numbers

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    boolean isPrime = true;
    for(int x = 3; x < 1000; x++) {
        int num = ( (x * (x + 1)) / 2);
        // formula for checking the sum of integers one through x
        for(int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
            if(num % i == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                // if it's false it is not prime
            }
            if(isPrime == true) {
                System.out.println(x);
                // prints out the original number, the sum of the numbers before it is a prime number
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In other words, it should take a number, x, plug it into the formula and see if the number returned by the formula is a prime number. However, I'm getting long strings of numbers that aren't prime (like 3, 4, 5, 6, 7...).

Comment: Oh, I see what that sum is for

Comment: Put if(isPrime==ture) out of second loop..

Comment: No number will be prime number is its generated from multiply of 2 numbers (>1)

Comment: @gifpif.com it's not generated from multiply of 2 numbers. It's a half of those numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small logical issue. You should print a prime when it is a prime in deed. It means that it doesn't divide by all of those numbers. So move it outside the loop.

```
for(int x = 3; x < 1000; x++) {

    int num = ( (x * (x + 1)) / 2);
    // formula for checking the sum of integers one through x

    if (num%2 == 0) {
        isPrime = false;
    }

    for(int i = 3; isPrime && i < num ; i += 2) {

        if(num % i == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            // if it's false it is not prime
        }
    }

    if(isPrime == true) {
        System.out.println(x);
        // prints out the original number, the sum of the numbers before it is a prime number
    }
}
```

I also added some optimisation - no need to check if n%4, n%6 itd is 0, when it's not even as well as checking if divides by large numbers when already found one divisor.

On the other hand it's impossible for `x > 2`. **The only `x` for which it works is `2`.**

Comment: How can any number will be prime when is created from multiply by sum numbers?

Comment: OP should also: **a)** init `isPrime` as true, and **b)** could break when `isPrime` gets false to stop checking that number and move on to the next

Comment: @Alfabravo the initial is prime is ok in OP's code. Instead of breaking I prefere adding the condition to the loop. Clean code suggests not using a break statement in loops.

Comment: @gifpif.com it's not a multiply, it's a sum.

Comment: @xenteros int num = ( (x * (x + 1)) / 2);

Answer (score 4):

The sum of integers from 1 to x is x*(x+1)/2.

Either x *or* x+1 is even, so the sum is **always** the product of 2 integers -- either x*((x+1)/2) *or* (x/2)*(x+1).

A prime cannot be made as the product of two integers unless those two integers are 1 and itself, so, if x is "lucky", then either (x+1)/2==1 *or* x/2==1 *or* x+1==1 *or* x==1, i.e., x is either 0, 1 or 2.

Since 0 doesn't count...

**1 and 2 are the only lucky numbers**

Comment: Ahha.  It's a troll question.  This makes sense.  I got my code to work but somehow, the only answer I got was 3.

Answer (score 0):

At every step of your inner for loop you are checking if it is prime. Because it defaults as being prime, if it isn't found not prime in the first check it shows.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

  boolean isPrime = true;

  for (int x = 3; x < 1000; x++) {

   int num = ((x * (x + 1)) / 2);
   // formula for checking the sum of integers one through x

   for (int i = 2; i < num; i++) {

    if (num % i == 0) {
     isPrime = false;
     // if it's false it is not prime
    }
  }

    if (isPrime == true) { 
     System.out.println(x);
     // prints out the original number, the sum of the numbers before it is a prime number
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

it's impossible.  But here is my solution using streams!!

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(
                IntStream.range(2, 1000000)
                         .map(e->factor(e))
                         .filter(e -> isPrime(e))
                         .boxed()
                         .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))
                );

    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int input) {
        for (int i=2;i<input;i++) {
            if (input%i==0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static int factor(int input) {
        return ( (input * (input + 1)) / 2);

    }
}
```